# why both cannot display the same result?

Tags: angular, typescript

[Link](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/toh-pt2/eplnkr.html)

[Link](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/displaying-data/eplnkr.html)

In link one if we remove Const the program wont run. Why?
<strike>Also if we use array implementation of link one in link two or vice versa.
It wont work.</strike> 
It works.
What is difference between both the implementations?

Comment: please remove the angularjs tag since this question is for angular2+

Comment: It looks like you're linking to an off-site example. Please include a [MCVE] in your question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link#1 defines `HEROES` as a variable. The variable declaration, in typescript,  starts  with `(var|let|const)` . Here is an information https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html.
Removing the "const" declaration invalidates the typescript definition, hence the error in console "Unexpected token ]"

Links#2 defines `heroes` as a property. Without prefix declaration, the property is public, by default. Here is information about class and properties in typescript https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

**Update:**
Can you please clarify statement below.

> Also if we use array implementation of link one in link two or vice
>   versa. **It wont work**

The Link#1 array declaration style works in Link#2 example. Like so:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from './hero';

const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <h2>My favorite hero is: {{myHero.name}}</h2>
  <p>Heroes:</p>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
      {{ hero.name }}
      </li>
  </ul>
  <p *ngIf="heroes.length > 3">There are many heroes!</p>
`
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  heroes = HEROES;
  myHero = this.heroes[0];
}
```

Comment: Didn't import FormsModules. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can answer your second question. Since in first link there is no constructor inside Hero class. When you create array like second link it will create object but values will not be initialized. But if you use first link array creation in second link it will work fine.

For first question since you are declaring it outside class you have to specify variable type either var or const or let it will act as local variable.